# How to create a background of shape shown in the figure

Tags: html, css, background-color

I want to create a background of color #F74422 in the top right corner of the html page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. This will hide the rest of the circle by giving minus values to the circle top and right and with the rem values, margins will be responsive

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -5rem;
  margin-right: -5rem;
  background-color: #F74422;
  border-radius: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: hey adithya, thanks. Hope it helped as well. and already did to your question as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.content {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color:#000;
 position: relative;
}
.content:before {
 content: '';
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 background: #F74422 ;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
 </div>
```